# Fetch data by name Laravel-8

Tags: jquery, laravel-8

Here I have many different tables in my database one of them is named matches..

This is my matchhs table image
[image]

This is my scores table
[image]

This is my web.php

```
Route::get('public_scores', [PublicController::class, 'view'])->name('dropdownView');
```

This is my PublicController.php

```
public function view()
{
  $match = Matchh::all();
  $data = Score::where('matchhs.id','=','scores.id');
  return view('public.index', compact('match','data'));
}
```

This is my index.blade.php

```
@foreach ($match as $row)
        <button id="table1" value="{{ $row->id }}">{{ $row->match_name }}</button>
        {{-- If I click the button then it will take me to table --}}
    @endforeach

    <table #table1>
        {{-- Table will show me only those data where button match_name value and
            table match_name will same --}}
        @foreach ($data as $row)
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Match Name</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $row->match_name }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
```

This is my web view image
[image]

In my web view, you can see I have fetched match_name from my matchhs table in buttons. If I click any button, I want it to show me all data from the scores table where the match_name of matchs table and match_name of the scores table are same.

This is what I have done but I didn`t get the accepted result Please help if you can I have been stuck on this its four days

Note: I am just a beginner of laravel

Comment: First, you need to define a relation between matches and scores in your `Match` model. after that if you need to load scores data on the current page by just pressing a button, you have to send an ajax request with the id of match name as a parameter to the backend and fetch scores data that belongs to the match id and then render it on the screen.

Comment: can you linked me any tutorian

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships |  https://codingdriver.com/ajax-post-request-laravel-example.html