# Proper usage of the Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I have a page where I want to list some countries and states I have in my database, each one has their own controllers. I'd like to know if this is the proper way to do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  </head>
    <body>
        <?php $states = App\Http\Controllers\StatesController::getStates(); ?>
        @foreach($states as $state)
            <p>{{$state->name}}</p>
        @endforeach

        <?php $countries= App\Http\Controllers\CountriesController::getCountries(); ?>
        @foreach($countries as $country)
            <p>{{$country->name}}</p>
        @endforeach
    </body>
</html>
```

The controllers are perfoming SQL queries and returning them as arrays, such as:

```
 public static function getStates() {
        $states= DB::table('states')->get();

        return $states;
    }
```

Since I'm not using `view` and not setting up at any routes to do this, is this ok according to the MVC format? If not, how could I make it?

Comment: If you're not using a view generated by a controller action then IMO it's not really MVC. Any reason you're doing it like this? You can of course do as you please, but it depends to what extent you want to stick to the MVC pattern.

Comment: @ADyson I don't know how to get both of these `get`s using the controller, given each controller will return a different view

Comment: Sounds like they should potentially be functions which a controller action would call to get data and put it into a combined ViewModel object, which would then be returned to a view. So rather than being controller actions themselves, they would be functions in the background logic/data layer of your application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is not wrong but not correct in the context of an MVC.

The workflow would be Route -> Controller -> View.

**web.php**

`Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\YourController::class, 'index']);`

**YourController.php**

```php
public function index() {
    return view('index', [
       // 'states' => DB::table('states')->get(),
       'states' => \App\Models\States::all(),
       'countries' => \App\Models\Countries::all(),
     ]);
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  </head>
    <body>
        @foreach($states as $state)
            <p>{{$state->name}}</p>
        @endforeach

        @foreach($countries as $country)
            <p>{{$country->name}}</p>
        @endforeach
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So, for each `.blade` I should have a method to return its view? I was trying to reduce the amount of methods to perform this, but if this is the best practice I'd go for it,

Comment: @AkariOozora If I have understood you correctly now :-) In general, you can say that each view has a corresponding controller method. This is the common way.

Comment: Also, it seems the SQL queries are being performed at the Models, is this right?

Comment: @AkariOozora Basically yes, without going into more detail. You can view the model in laravel as a repository. `Model::all(), Model::find(1), Model:where("id",1)->get()`

Comment: Just for curiosity: since I'm working with content of different models, I should work with with a separate controller? For instance, if my page just need the countries, I use the CountriesController, but since it is using both, I create a separate controller to deal with this.

Comment: @AkariOozora No you don't need to. The controller receives the request for that one particular resource (for example /index.html). The controller now takes care of loading all the data from different models. For more complex requests, it makes sense to work with a service and the controller only validates the requests. but you don't need that in this particular case.

Comment: I thought each class had its separate controller, so I should have a single controller which will load the models data and return the views? I

Comment: @AkariOozora short answer: no ;-)

Comment: @AkariOozora Long answer: Not every model needs a controller. As I said, the controller accepts the request for a particular resource and organises the data. Small example why: If you don't want to show your users to your site visitors via the resource user/{id} you don't need a controller userController. But in your dashboard you already want to show the user his data. So for example the DashboardController would use the User Model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400777/fetch-data-by-name-laravel-8