# Undefined variable by using eloquent relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here is the error returned by Laravel :

> ErrorException compact(): Undefined variable $lists

I am trying to join multiples tables like :
**Tops** has many **Lists** and **Lists** has many **Medias**

I have this code in my TopController :

```
 $tops = Top::with(
                    'user:id,name,email',
                    'lists:id',
                    'categories:title,slug'
                )->paginate(20);
```

I have no problem for retrieve user and categories datas but the lists variable seems to be undefined and I do not understand why.

Here is the Liste.php Model :

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }


      public function tops()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Top::class);
    }



      public function medias()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Medias::class);
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

https://pastebin.com/Anv4AhVe

Comment: Where do you get this error? If it is coming from TopController, please provide the controller's complete code.

Comment: I added the TopController file to my op

Comment: Hell, I guess I understood... I have simply no var for this name, I have to use it directly in my view... Ill try it. Edit : I was right.. pffff tired. Thank you

Comment: yes, there is no`$lists` variable in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to define a $lists variable in your index method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400777/fetch-data-by-name-laravel-8